# How to setup nginx with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have nginx config and docker compose but I am not able to link them together properly.

default.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    upstream docker_nginx {
        server nginx:6000;
    }

    server {

         location / {
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_pass         http://localhost:4000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        
        location /jwt/user/ {
          proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          pproxy_pass         http://localhost:4000;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

Docker compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
    reverseproxy:
        image: nginx
        container_name: docker_nginx
        ports:
            - 6000:6000
        volumes:
            - ./services:/default.conf
        restart: always

    jwt:
        build: ./jwt
        image: jwt:1.0
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./jwt
```

I want to listen on port 6000 and route request to a service on port 4000. I tried running `http://nginx:6000/` and `http://localhost:6000/` but I get this:

```
This site can’t be reached. The web page at http://localhost:6000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

Comment: Tried changing port number other than 6000 ??

Comment: @Panther Yes I tried but no luck

Comment: You've to explicitly tell nginx to listen on 6000 port otherwise default would be 80 and therefore you've to map `6000:80` in your docker-compose file

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you my [repo](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker), you can check my docker-compose.yml, it uses several services and are proxied using Nginx and are worked together.

On this [link](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/blob/master/nginx/default.conf) you’ll find a default.conf file and it contains several Nginx upstream configuration please take a look at how I used docker-compose service references there.

Inside the [client/](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/tree/master/client) directory, I also have another Nginx as a web server of a react.js project.

On [server/](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/tree/master/server) directory, it has a Node.js API, It connects to Redis and Postgres SQL database also built from docker-compose.yml.

I think this use case can be useful for you and other users!

Comment: It is very!
It should be of great help if someone took this repo, and made a blog about it explaining the steps. Its a deep dive if you are not very familiar with compose files in combination with multiple services and nginx

Comment: Nice @Nebulosar thanks for your comment, This week I'll try to write an article on medium for other topic but I'll try to help with docker-compose, and multiple services with nginx in the future.

Comment: That looks great, having at least a bit of docs (at least for those who may not know that they need to run `docker-compose up` to get it running) would make it better. Probably an NGINX noob question but why would you not define all the NGINX config in a single file that would be then handled by the `multi-docker_nginx` service? Or is there a benefit in having the one in `./client`?

Comment: Hello Berkman, a simple answer could be to decouple the services, you first pass the traffic through NGINX and then create upstream connections to other hosts.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things which are misconfigured.

1. config file is mapped to wrong location

It should be `./services/default.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

2. You've to explicitly tell `nginx` (in conf file) to listen to `6000` port or otherwise map your `6000` port to `80` port inside nginx (default for nginx) `"6000:80"`
3. Yes, and as suggested in other answer, instead of proxying to `localhost:4000` you have to proxy it to `jwt:4000`.

For more on nginx in docker see it's doc https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Answer (score 0):

Should `- ./services:/default.conf` be something like `- ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enables/default.conf`?

Also try replacing `proxy_pass         http://localhost:4000;` with `proxy_pass         http://jwt:4000;` and you probably don't need the `upstream` section.

The "proxy_pass" is the address of the proxied service from *within* the network created by docker compose - and each service's domain is the same as its name in `docker-compose.yml`

I have never used `upstream`, but if you want to use it, I think you have to put this

```
upstream docker-jwt {
  server jwt:4000;
}

# and

proxy_pass         http://docker-jwt;
```

but as I put above, I would skip that and just put `http://jwt:4000` as the proxied address.

You also seem to have a typo here: `pproxy_pass         http://localhost:4000;`

But if you leave the typo, and look at the docker compose logs, you will hopefully see an error from nginx, which means that you successfully mapped the config file